# Robocopy with logs

Tags: robocopy

I want to use robocopy for one copying work where whole directory and it's subdirectories with files needs to be copied, but also the log files must contains the logs of copied as well skipped files details. I was using below command robocopy src dest /e /logs:dest
But it's not working for me, can anyone please suggest the required command that can be used for this purpose. Thanks.